# Android: change text color of an item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have Implemented `Side Menu Navigation`. The left side menu is a `listview` and `onclick` of item opens an Activity. I want to change the text color of an item when the user clicks on it and remain this color of item until he clicks on another item. And after click on another item change the color of first item to the default color and change the other item color and so on. Any help or code example will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `CheckedTextView` for text of list item and set `android:textColor` value to a [color state list resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

Remember to set list view: `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` as well